# Is it possible to respond to a click on a tiop level menu item?

Tags: qt, qmenu

Is it possible to respond to a click on a top level menu item?  For example, referring to the image below, is it possible to run code when the "Help" menu item is clicked?

[image: Simple menu picture]

If so, how do I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `QMenu::aboutToShow()` signal and do the following:

```
connect(helpMenu, SIGNAL(aboutToShow()), this, SLOT(onHelpMenuClicked()));
```

where `helpMenu` is pointer to your Help menu and `onHelpMenuClicked()` is slot that will be called as soon as you click on the `Help` menu.